# WCF passing class with <T>

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i got a datacontract ,
something like:

```
public class MyClass<T>() where T : MyBaseClass
{
   public   List<T> MyList { get; set;}
}

public class SubClassOne : MyBaseClass
{
}
public class SubClassOne : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

on the client side i got something liek

```
MyClass<SubClassOne> FirstClass = new MyClassOfSubClassOneHXlyzk1V()
```

Same for the other sub classes , how can i transffer this class in WCF so i will be able to get MyClass without the OfTHXlyzk1V part

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a function of how WCF generates the class names for generics in an attempt to prevent class name collision. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx) for specific details.

You have two options for solving this:

1) Modify `MyClass` to specify the name that you want in the client:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyClass{0}")]
public class MyClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass
```

Assuming the return value is `MyClass<SubClassOne>`, this will generate a client name of `MyClassSubClassOne`.

2) Move all of your shared classes (classes used in the WCF service and client) into a project that can be included in each application (primarily for the purpose of namespace resolution).

Then in the WCF Client, right click on the service reference and choose `Configure Service Reference...` and ensure the `Reuse types in all referenced assemblies` is checked.

Here is a very brief [MSDN how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653.aspx) on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [KnownType] to declare the types you want to use for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Scroll to - **"Known Types Using Open Generic Methods"**